# How to place comma separated values into newline and remove all the id's before including colon

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have below command output from the Linux System where it fetches the all the account names by comma separated which I want to be placed into newline's,  so remove all the command and place individual account name into newline.

```
$ getent group pi_infra
pi_infra:*:5899:pxf59093,pxv07744,pxa02374,pxa07513,pxa08599,pxa11102,pxa30995,pxa34158,pxf07822,pxf29346,pxf30902,pxf31604,pxf31606,pxf31953,pxf34985,pxf41740,pxf41778,pxf43236,pxf43917,pxf45518,pxf46461,pxf49051,pxf58440,pxf58523,pxf58621,pxf60794,pxf60938,pxf61299,pxf63061,pxp08000,pxp25916,pxp42841,pxp68003,pxp69833,pxp87972

$ cat pi_in| sed 's/,/\n/g'

$ cat pi_in| tr ',' '\n'
```

Result From the above.

```
pi_infra:*:5899:pxf59093
pxv07744
pxa02374
pxa07513
pxa08599
pxa11102
pxa30995
pxa34158
pxf07822
pxf29346
pxf30902
pxf31604
pxf31606
pxf31953
pxf34985
pxf41740
pxf41778
pxf43236
pxf43917
pxf45518
pxf46461
pxf49051
pxf58440
pxf58523
pxf58621
pxf60794
pxf60938
pxf61299
pxf63061
pxp08000
pxp25916
pxp42841
pxp68003
pxp69833
pxp87972
```

As i want to remove all the stuff before `:` and only want ID printed hence i've chosen to use below.

```
$ cat pi_in| cut -d":" -f4 | tr ',' '\n'
pxf59093
pxv07744
pxa02374
pxa07513
pxa08599
pxa11102
pxa30995
pxa34158
pxf07822
pxf29346
pxf30902
pxf31604
pxf31606
pxf31953
pxf34985
pxf41740
pxf41778
pxf43236
pxf43917
pxf45518
pxf46461
pxf49051
pxf58440
pxf58523
pxf58621
pxf60794
pxf60938
pxf61299
pxf63061
pxp08000
pxp25916
pxp42841
pxp68003
pxp69833
pxp87972
```

This above works fine but looking it this all can be integrated into one rather using `tr` and `cut` two times distinctly.

Preferably `awk` or `sed` would be appropriate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `awk` could you please try following.

```
awk -F':' '{gsub(",",ORS,$4);print $4}'  Input_file
```

***2nd solution:***

```
awk '{sub(/.*:/,"");gsub(/,/,ORS)} 1'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$ sed 's/.*://; y/,/\n/' file
pxf59093
pxv07744
pxa02374
...
```

`s/.*://` removes everything preceding the last colon, and the colon itself, and `y/,/\n/` does what `tr` does in your approach.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'y/,/\n/;/:/!P;D' file
```

Translate `,`'s to newlines and don't print any line with a `:` in it.

N.B. The solution by @oguz ismail is more efficient and faster (with regards to a sed solution).